# How do I read in a file and designate the first line as a root to a binary node?

Tags: java, file, input

Ok. I am working on a 20 questions style game and I can't get my program just to read the first line of the read in file and build the binary tree from there. The file is being read in but it goes straight to the last entry in the read in file.

```
    public class Questions(){
      File file = new File("input");
      Scanner INPUT = null;
      try{
        INPUT = new Scanner(file);
      } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
      }
      while(INPUT.hasNext()){
        String line = INPUT.nextLine();
        root = new BinaryNode<String>();
        if(line.length() - 1 == '?'){
          return;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't go over the entire code, but this jumped out at me right away...

```
while(INPUT.hasNext()){
  String line = INPUT.nextLine();
  root = new BinaryNode<String>(line);
  if(line.length() - 1 == '?'){
    return;
  }
```

Here you just keep re-assigning the `root` over and over again with a `new BinaryNode<String>` with the current `line`. You'll never end up with anymore than one string at the end. You should have a structure of nodes that provides an `insert(...){...}` of some sort so that you can build the structure.

You also should be doing...

```
if(line.charAt(line.length() - 1 == '?'){...}
```

The way you have it now, its asking if the length of `line` is equal to `?`, that's not what you want.

**Edit:** (based on comment)
A structure, say a list, would have a node member as the root. Assuming the list is doubly linked the nodes would have a `prev` and `next` reference to the previous and next nodes in the list. When you insert into that list it would check if `root == null`. If true root would be set with the data, `prev` and `next` would be set to `null`. If false you would iterate up the list until there was a `null` at `next`, you would then store a new node there and so on.

Yes, you could still keep the files separate if that's what you're asking. The questions are still nodes of string type, so that's no problem, you just need a way to store *more* than 1 of them.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I don't understand what you mean by having a structure of nodes?

Comment: Could be any structure where you can have many nodes, a binary search tree, list, queue - it would depend on your requirements. You could build a simple list of your own or you use Java utility classes.

Comment: I only have one other .java file in the directory and it is called BinaryNode.java. I would really like to just keep that one and my Questions.java files. Is this even possible?

Comment: I do not have prev and next methods in the BinaryNode.java file. I have setLeft(), setRight(), setItem(), getLeft(), getRight(), getItem(), and isLeaf(). Are these the kinds of things I need to look at. Sorry I am super stupid with programming.

Comment: @Jargle: OK, that's a tree then. That means you're setting left and right based on comparing the values; right? So in that case you'd, in the event root isn't null, decide if it should go left or right, then continue doing so until you've found the appropriate position, then place it there. So you have the structure, my example is a list. In any event the main point to be taken away is that you're not doing anything for that. You need to have the insert method that does that for you.

Comment: Ok. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: @Jargle: [Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Insertion)

Comment: Can I just add the insert method into my BinaryNode.java without having to add a BinarySearchTree.java?

Comment: @Jargle: Last comment since you cannot chat. You have to decide if that's appropriate. You have the node, so if `Questions` has the root, maybe it's a `QuestionTree` and you put the insert there. You don't necessarily need a custom Tree class, but if you don't you'll have to re-write it for some other purpose, or have some funky inheritance going on. You came to the conclusion you needed a binary tree node so why fight that. You could just have an `ArrayList` of strings and not worry about it.